# kedro context and catalog missing from ipython session

Tags: ipython, kedro

I launched ipython session and trying to load a dataset.
I am running
df = catalog.load("test_dataset")
Facing the below error
`NameError: name 'catalog' is not defined`

I also tried %reload_kedro but got the below error

`` UsageError: Line magic function `%reload_kedro` not found. ``

Even not able to load context either.
I am running the kedro environment from a Docker container.
I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

new in 0.17.5 there is a fallback option, please run the following commands in your Jupyter/IPython session:

```py
%load_ext kedro.extras.extensions.ipython
%reload_kedro <path_to_project_root>
```

This should help you get up and running.

Comment: I am running kedro 0.17.6 on Windows and trying to do the spaceflights tutorial but running into the same problem from kedro ipython session.  Specifically, it says "NameError: name 'catalog' is not defined".

Comment: In that situation @user13999 you have an issue with your catalog. We're going to improve the error message in the future, but for now if you `kedro run` on the command line it will tell you what your issue is.